# LinkedIn Authentication Window Auto-Closes With Prompt in IE, Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have an application deployed in three environments, that use the LinkedIn JS API to open the LinkedIn authentication window. In two of those environments, when the LinkedIn window opens, it immediately tries to close itself with a prompt, in IE and Edge (works correctly in Chrome and Firefox, and in all browsers (including IE and Edge) in the third environment):

[image: Authentication Self-Close Dialog]

If you answer "Yes" to this prompt, the window closes and the user can't authenticate. If you answer "No", then a LinkedIn 404 page is shown.

I tried changing permissions for the associated API keys, and generating new API keys entirely, but none of those changes caused the error to go away in the two environments that are failing, or caused the error to appear in the environment where there are currently no issues.

Disabling Protected Mode in IE 11 fixes the issue, and re-enabling it causes the issue to return, but there is no such option in Edge. Disabling extensions with `iexplore.exe -extoff {url}` does not fix the problem.

You can reproduce the issue in IE or Edge on: https://jobs.sap.com/job/Palo-Alto-Senior-Quality-Specialist-Job-CA-94301/338144501/ by clicking Apply Now > Apply with LinkedIn, entering a fake e-mail address, and clicking Start. The self-closing window should appear. You should find that doing the same on https://sap.valhalla.qa.jobs2web.com/job/San-Mateo-Support-Account-Manager-Job-CA-94401/2160465700/ works correctly, where the LinkedIn authentication window appears, ready for user input.

This has been replicated by others, both on and off of the network I'm working on. I don't see any errors or warnings in the developer tools console. There aren't any browser plug-ins, etc. installed that might be blocking something.

Any ideas as to what I can check to try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the page that is trying to close itself? Without a reproduction url, we cannot debug it for you. "Disabling Protected Mode" indicates that it has something to do with a browser addon or plugin, probably a form filling addon. the first step in troubleshooting any web browser issue is to test it in noAddons mode (Start>Run>iexplore.exe -extoff [url] or you can manage your IE addons individually from Tools>Manage Addons>Show all addons. Linked In should not allow formfillers to autofill their login screens..

Comment: I've tried your tip with `-extoff` but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. I've added URLs for debugging.

Comment: The LinkedIn authentication screen has always allowed form auto-fillers to populate the authentication fields, and does so still today -- if you can get the window to open in the first place, which is the new and interesting issue here. :-)

Comment: have you tested in noAddons mode to confirm that a form filler addon is involved. Authentication provider services like likedin and FB also use "persistent" credential verification, which stores a token in the fb or linkedin cookie. Test also in InPrivate mode, where site cookies are sandboxed and third party addons are disabled by default.